# Need helping linking mutilple sheets together into a master sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have a large workbook full of employee information for keeping track of employee certifications.  What I am wanting to do it to link the employee certification information on different sheets to one master sheet.  I have been able to create links and use the data, but when I sort the employees by last name, the links from the other sheets are not staying with the employees, it is staying with the cell reference from the corresponding sheet, therefore not providing correct information for employees.  This creates a problem for me when I am adding in new employees and sorting the list by the last names.  Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Vlookup should work if you have a common column in all worksheets (e.g. Employee ID). You can then list all unique, say, employee IDs in your Master sheet and then lookup relevant value from other sheets. You need to ensure the format of this common column in all worksheets are the same.

Otherwise, you can try use VBA loop to go through each sheet and copy paste the value you need to the Master sheet. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using vlookup() using employee code as key. There are lots of example out there.

```
http://www.timeatlas.com/5_minute_tips/general/learning_vlookup_in_excel#.Urz2IdIW3ic
http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/ss/vlookup.htm
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx
```